# How to generate file and re-use its content with terrafrom

Tags: terraform

I would like to generate ssh keys with a local-exec then read the content of the file.

```
resource "null_resource" "generate-ssh-keys-pair" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "test" -P "" -f "testkey"
    EOT
  }
}

data "local_file" "public-key" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.generate-ssh-keys-pair]
  filename = "testkey.pub"
}

data "local_file" "private-key" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.generate-ssh-keys-pair]
  filename = "testkey"
}
```

terraform plan works but when I run the apply, I got error on testkey and testkey.pub don't exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Instead of generating a file using an external command and then reading it in, I would suggest to use the Terraform `tls` provider to generate the key within Terraform itself, using [`tls_private_key`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key):

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    tls = {
      source = "hashicorp/tls"
    }
  }
}

resource "tls_private_key" "example" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}
```

The `tls_private_key` resource type exports two attributes that are equivalent to the two files you were intending to read in your example:

- `tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem`: the private key in PEM format
- `tls_private_key.example.public_key_openssh`: the public key in the format OpenSSH expects to find in `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Please note the warning in the `tls_private_key` documentation that using this resource will cause the private key data to be saved in your Terraform state, and so you should protect that state data accordingly. That would also have been true for your approach of reading files from disk using data resources, because any value Terraform has available for use in expressions must always be stored in the state.

Comment: This shouldn't be used for production though, the key will be stored in the tfstate file

Answer (score 0):

I **run your code** and there are no problems with it. It **correctly** generates `testkey` and `testkey.pub`.

So whatever causes it to fail for you, its not this snipped of code you've provided in the question. The fault must be outside the code snipped.

Answer (score 0):

Generating an SSH key in Terraform is inherently insecure because it gets stored in the tfstate file, however I had a similar problem to solve and thought that the most secure/usable was to use a secret management service + using a cloud bucket for the backend:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.3.0"
    }
  }

  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "tfstatebucket"
    prefix  = "terraform/production"
  }
}

//Import Ansible private key from Google Secrets Manager
resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "ansible_private_key" {
  secret_id = var.ansible_private_key_secret_id
  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
}

data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "ansible_private_key"{
  secret  = google_secret_manager_secret.ansible_private_key.secret_id
  version = var.ansible_private_key_secret_id_version_number
}


resource "local_file" "ansible_imported_local_private_key" {
    sensitive_content   = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.ansible_private_key.secret_data
    filename            = var.ansible_imported_local_private_key_filename
    file_permission     = "0600"
}
```

In the case of GCP, I would add the secret in Google Secrets Manager, then use `terraform import` on the secret, which will in turn write it to the backend bucket. That way it doesn't get stored in Git as plain text, you can have the key file local to your project (.terraform shouldn't be under version control), and it's arguably more secure in the bucket.

So the workflow essentially is:

```
Human --> Secret Manager

Secret Manager --> Terraform Import --> GCS Bucket Backend
                                    |--> Create .terraform/ssh_key 

.terraform/ssh_key --> Terraform/Ansible/Whatever
```

Hashicorp Vault would be another way to address this